# how to set prompt textbox field in js as required field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set the textbox field in the prompt box as a required field?

```
var answer=prompt('Reason for deletion?');
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `window.prompt` is modal, you can use following logic:

```
while(!answer){
    var answer=prompt('Reason for deletion?');
};
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Just so you know, if you use the "prevent this page from showing more popup boxes", this while loop will continue until FF crashes.

Comment: This is what I expected

Answer (score 4):

If you want be able to also cancel prompt it's possible to modify condition from @A.Wolf post.

```
do{
    var answer = prompt('Reason for deletion? Note is required');
} while(answer !== null && answer === "")
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cxfLvap2/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way of what @Petr Špaček did. I used a function to make it a required response. Here it is:

```html
<script>
function requiredFunction() {
  var answer = prompt('Reason for deletion?');
  if (answer == "") {
    requiredFunction();
  }
}
requiredFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var answer=prompt('Reason for deletion?');
    if(answer !=null)
    {
    /* Your code */
    }
    else if(!answer)
    {
    alert('Entry Required');
    return false;
    }
else
{
alert('Entry Cancelled By User');
    return false;
}
```

Use this and also check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

Comment: What about an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `requiredPrompt` function to `onclick` handler then you can return the function itself if the input hasn't a value.

```
<script>
    function requiredPrompt() {
        var answer = prompt('Reason for deletion?');
        if (answer === '') return requiredPrompt();
        
        // you logic if entered a value...
    }
</script>
```